# Build an array in jquery using loop in dictionary

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to pass array value for creating graph of jplot function. In Layout cshtml it consist of jquery function for creating the graph and it have an array in the form of:

```
var s1 = [['06/15/2009 16:00:00', 112000], ['06/16/2009 16:00:00', 122000], ['06/17/2009 16:00:00', 104000], ['06/18/2009 16:00:00', 99000], ['06/19/2009 16:00:00', 121000]];
```

I have passed dictionary value to this layout using viewbag and use following code to loop through dictionary.

```
  @foreach (KeyValuePair<String, int> kvp in ViewBag.dateRange)
                    {  
                        @kvp.Key
                       @kvp.Value          
                    }
```

How can I built above array for jquery function using razor engine. Dictionary have string and int where string is date value and int is total number value.

Comment: Why do you want to use ['06/15/2009 16:00:00', 112000] as array, but not as object?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@{
    var dic = ViewBag.dateRange as Dictionary<String,int>;
}

var s1 = [@(String.Join(",", dic.Select(d => String.Format("['{0}',{1}]", d.Key, d.Value)));)];
```